Adding shelves to angled/vertical beams in attic
I’ve seen posts where doing things with attic trusses can be a no-no but saw others that say otherwise.
I was thinking of putting a couple pieces of plywood between 2 sets of vertical and horizontal 2x4’s to add a little storage.
But then got concerned about adding weight.
Here’s what I was thinking:

Does this look like it could be a problem?
I am thinking two shelves over 3 horizontal and 3 diagonal beams.
Here is my crappy attempt at a 3D rendering.


It is the weight per unit area that becomes the problem.  The weight force on a couple of small shelves on one truss, will be more than the same weight spread out over a 4x8 piece of plywood supported be a few trusses.

Agreed, not a good idea to place weight on 1 truss.  Tie 3 or 4 trusses together with a 2x4s and place a shelf on those, spreading the weight across multiple trusses.  Still don't place more than maybe 5lbs per sq' on any shelf.

@RMDman thx for chiming in.  Yeah, that picture is lacking. I added another image.  The plywood  would be spread out over 3 horizontal & 3 vertical beams.

@crip659 Thanks for commenting. I added another image so you can better see what I mean.

You should be Ok with not alot of weight on the shelves.

Some buildings/houses have a load bearing wall under the centre drop down or some trusses have a wall under them.  These trusses can handle a bit more weight.  Most people who add shelves do tend to add as much stuff as they can to them.  Most trusses are not made to hold too much weight.  You must promise to not add too much weight or you will be wearing your roof on your head.

Yes, I would try to put the shelves above a wall, if possible.

Thank you for all the answers!
